# How to calculate with reduxform?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am a redux-form newbie and trying to add two values, 2 fields that look like this:

```
 <Field
          className="uk-input"
          name="amount1"
          component="input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="dollars"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
```

I use a function that is called in the handleChange event:

```
handleChange = () => {
    console.log("hoer");
    this.props.change(
      "selectingFormValues",
      "totaal",
      total(this.props.amount1 + this.props.amount2)
    );
  };
```

How can I calculate the total and store the total in the redux-form store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `componentDidUpdate` (and remove `handleChange`) to calculate the updated sum:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const { amount1, amount2 } = this.props;
    const tootal = parseFloat(amount1 || 0) + parseFloat(amount2 || 0);
    this.props.change("selectingFormValues", "totaal", tootal);
  }
```

and change the total component to be an `input`:

```
<Field className="uk-select" name="totaal" component="input" />
```

See updated example https://codesandbox.io/s/jl6pwj2r75

Alternatively, you can do the calculation in selector instead than within `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.props.change("selectingFormValues", "totaal", this.props.tootal);
}
```

and in selector:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { amount1, amount2 } = selector(state, "amount1", "amount2");
  const tootal = parseFloat(amount1 || 0) + parseFloat(amount2 || 0);
  return {
    amount1,
    amount2,
    tootal
  };
};
```

See this second [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4rnno9053)

Comment: Suppose I have more calculations and locations where I want to use the calculations . How can I do this using selectors?